# is it possible to restart the already terminated process in python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Here is the example code for my question:

```
import multiprocessing, time
def nopr():
        i=0
        while 1:
                i = i+1
                print i
                time.sleep(1)

p = multiprocessing.Process(target =  nopr)
print "process started"
p.start()
time.sleep(04)
print "process ended"
p.terminate()
time.sleep(1)


p.start()
```

Answer (score 7):

No you cannot start a terminated process, you would have to recreate it :

```
import multiprocessing, time
def nopr():
    i=0
    while 1:
        i = i+1
        print i
        time.sleep(1)

p = multiprocessing.Process(target =  nopr)
print "process started"
p.start()
time.sleep(04)
print "process ended"
p.terminate()
time.sleep(1)

p = multiprocessing.Process(target =  nopr) # recreate
p.start()
```

Comment: thank u so much for ur solution it worked !!!!
yahooo !!!!
 the terminated process will not be using the cpu and memory right ???

Comment: No it won't unless you have subprocesses ending up as zombies but it's not the case in your code :) don't forget to mark it as answer if it works for you!